# How do I add a new object to the end of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

How do I add a new object to an array and how do I return the update array with the new object added to the end? this is the data I have!

newCandy = {
candy:"Skittles" ,
inStock:200,
10,
};

and this is the function

function addNewcandy(inventory,newCandy)

Comment: `inventory.push(newCandy);`

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
const newArray = [...oldArray, newObject]
```